# Should useCallback always be used when passing a function as a prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the below code. If I pass the props `onUpdate` and `onDelete` as just functions - function objects in javascript - the child components always re-renders due to a props change in the profiler. The function is recreated and `onUpdate` and `onDelete` are now new props, makes sense to me.

However, if I add `useCallback`, they don't perceive a prop change, as this is the purpose of `useCallback`. So this leads to a few questions.

- What is the drawback to using `useCallback` for every function passed down to a child?
- Is there no benefit to using `useCallback` because the children will render because the parent rendered anyways?
- Why isn't this the default behavior? I know that this may not be answerable.

  ```
    <UpdateGroupInput
      onUpdate={useCallback(
        group => {
          const index = groups.findIndex(searchedGroup => searchedGroup.id === group.id);
          const newGroups = groups.slice();
          newGroups[index] = group;
          onChange(items, newGroups);
          hideAddItemModal();
        },
        [groups, items, onChange]
      )}
      onDelete={useCallback(
        id => {
          const newGroups = groups.filter(group => group.id !== id);
          const newItems = items.filter(item => item.group !== id);
          onChange(newItems, newGroups);
        },
        [groups, items, onChange]
      )}
      groups={groups}
      visible={viewUpdateGroup}
    ></UpdateGroupInput>
  ```

Comment: Aren't components rerendered by default anyway? I think what you are describing only affects memoized components? I assume it's not the default for three reasons: 1) Components always rerender by default anyway (I might be wrong). 2) There is no way for React to know when to recreate a callback. That's what you are telling React by passing the list of dependencies. 3) Wrong application of memoization can lead to bugs (component doesn't rerender even though it should). By rerendering everything by default, bugs are less likely and developers still have a chance to fine tune the render process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UseCallback is just a special version of `useMemo` that is just for use with functions. The advantage is that is stops you recreating the function on each render, which can cause you to break any other memoization further down your component tree.

Like any form of code optimisation the advantages may not be that great, it adds it’s own overhead that may outweigh any advantages and also adds complexity to your code.

To quote Knuth “Premature optimisation is the route of all evil”

Kent C. Dodds has a much more detailed look at this on his blog
https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback

Comment: I ran across that article in the past, but didn't fully read it until you recommended it. That clears it up.